# How to protect Files.walk from symbolic links recursion?

Tags: java, file, recursion, symlink

How to protect Files.walk from symbolic links  recursion?
Using Java or shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so follow links.

```
Stream<Path> stream = walk(startPath, maxDepth, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
```

However check every directory whether it is a symbolic link:

```
Files.isSymbolicLink(path) && Fles.isDirectory(path)
```

Use

```
Path realPath = path.toRealPath();
```

Then keeping a list of directories on is in, ancestors, one would prevent recursion. By doing for *every* directory a check in the ancestors, when a symbolic link is somewhere in the list/current path.

```
a > b > START:c > d > e > SYMBOLIC:f=a > b > c
```

(This still does not prevent visiting a directory twice, as the same or a subdirectory could be linked without recursion.)

Answer (score 2):

You can parametrize a `Files.walk` invocation with `FileVisitOption`s.

If you do not add `FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS`, the crawling will not follow symbolic links.

See API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitOption.html).

Comment: Thank you! But if I need to visit symlinks, which do not leads to the recursion?

Comment: @Arthur I don't think there would or should be a Java-based solution there. That would require the Java process to detect in advance whether a symlink is recursive and stop crawling there.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Files.walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) doesn't appear to be protectable for symbolic link recursion. You can limit the depth of the search by setting `maxDepth` to something reasonable, like i.d.k. 200 ish?

If you need a more robust method than arbitrarily limiting the depth you can implement a [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html)  which when it encounters a symbolic link does some checking to see if it is recursive and then decide if you want to follow it or not. Then use the visitor with [`Files.walkFileTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-). However this won't give you a nice stream of paths so you'll probably have to do some adjustments to your code.

As for detecting the symbolic links that are recursive I think you can do some sorcery with [`File.getCanonicalPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) and a hash map of visited canonical paths. I don't have a linux machine handy so I haven't tested this though, YMMV.

Whatever you do, don't use a `List` of visited paths as other answers suggest, as this will give you O(n²) time to iterate over the file system.